# Cannot Ping/ ssh over wifi

Tags: networking, wifi, ssh, pi-3b+, ping

I have read several forums and have tried many solutions. I have a new raspberry pi 3 B+. Up to this point I have connected an ethernet cable to remote into my RPi. Now I am trying to use wifi and it will not work. I need this as I am putting together soomething that requires wireless access. It has never worked and the results are not intermittent.

Here are things I have verified:

- I can ping/ssh the RPi fine from any client as long as the RPi is plugged into Ethernet.
- I also have a brand new RPi 4. This is not a problem for the RPi 4.
- I can ping/ssh into other clients other than the RPi3 that are using any network interface(LAN/5Ghz/2.4Ghz).
- Client Isolation is turned off.
- Static IPs didn't make a difference.
- I tried temporarily turning off my router firewall.
- I did a "history | grep nano" to find any configs that I had touched and reverted anything that could be relevant.

I am stumped. Any other pointers?

Comment: Do you have a console attached on RPi, serial is enough? Please, obtain any, it will be required to debug. Then, please check: does RPi itself have an internet connection? If yes, what is in all involved systems ARP tables? Will inbound SSH work immediately after you ping a connecting host from RPi? If it worked, were some ARP entries changed? If not worked, can you install tcpdump package on RPi and see what is going on an interface when you ping and when you try to connect? BTW, don't you have both wired and wireless connected (a safeguard question)?

Comment: How do you know the WiFi is connected?

Comment: "Any other pointers" try asking a Question with information. It works for the rest of us. (At least post `ip a && ip r`)

Comment: Please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/120055/edit) your question and add the output of these commands to it: `ip addr` and `ip route` and `sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`.

Comment: A simple ping from the raspberry pi somehow fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I used the raspberry pi to ping another device, I was then able to ping it back. Ssh and rdp work now, too. After a reboot, everything still works. Unfortunately, I did not check the arp table before hand, so I don't know the exact reason why it failed.

Comment: You can still check that. Stop all pings, disconnect from RPi and remove its ARP entry from the host, then try to connect from it to RPi. If that again won't work, but connectivity is restored after a single packet originating from RPi, that's an ARP issue. Please check that, if true, I'll post a detailed explanation what's going on.

Comment: Then you Nikita. I'd be interested in the actual reason.  I'm going to give that a try.